# how to display recently viewed products list on product details page - magento

Tags: magento, themes, product

I have used mobileshoppe theme for magento and trying to display recently viewed product list at product details page but some how its not working...

Added code below at catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="content">
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="product.recently.viewed" as="product_recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and below code at app\design\frontend\default\mobileshoppe\template\catalog\product\ view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_recently_viewed') ?>
```

I have tried the same with default theme and its also not working, can any one help me to figure out this issue ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

On the the product detail template (view.phtml) you have to be more specific in the xml where you want to place the block. See the example below using local.xml in the theme layout directory (app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/layout/local.xml) to insert the block. Here's an example from a site I'm working on. Ironically we are having problems with it displaying consistently, which I'm trying to figure out right now, but this is working most of the time! Try getting more specific in your catalog.xml and it should work. The xml is in local.xml, the echo is in catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>

<catalog_product_view> 
<reference name="content"> 
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" as="recently_viewed" />
    </reference>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace xml reference content to left.

Instead of this

```
  <reference name="content">
```

Use below and check

```
  <reference name="left">
```

As it is a part of sidebar so it should work with left / right column as you want to display in page.

Cheers!